# Changing how Magento 2 approximate prices in invoices

Tags: magento2, price, tax

we have a problem with how our `Magento 2 calculates total prices`, including `taxes`, on our `invoices`. We set up magento to `calculate the price with taxes` on every single line and then to add them up at the end, but we still get approximation issues. How does magento calculates that? Is it possible to change the way it approximate prices? It seems to be off, even if it's one cent, doing the same operations with a calculator.

Comment: Any news on that topic? We can't seem to find any answer, but approximations on the system are certainly off.